# How can i create an action when selecting in treeNode primefaces

Tags: rest, primefaces, client, nuxeo

I am making a jsf application using the Nuxeo Java client which is a rest api.
I have structured a primefaces tree that shows the titles of nuxeo documents.What i want to do is opening a page that shows the metadata of the nuxeo document or editing the document, when clicking in a node.Any idea?

Comment: Start with the primefaces showcase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an ajax behavior provided for select event, you can place this in the tree  :

```
<p:ajax event="select" update=":form:messages" listener="#{treeEventsView.onNodeSelect}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I hope the OP will start with documentation, showcase etc.... next time...